# Linear Independence of dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, spacetime-dimensions

Are the dimensions of spacetime curved by gravity, linearly independent?

Comment: What does it mean for a "dimension" to be linearly independent from another?

Comment: Vectors in a vector space are (or are not) linearly independent. The dimension of a vector space or manifold is a single natural number (or infinity) that describes the whole space, so it’s a fundamentally different concept.

Answer (score 0):

The question is awkwardly phrased, but if I understood it correctly then, for a general regular surface yes  the number of linearly independent vectors of the tangent space is the dimension of said surface

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not written very well, anyway...

The dimension of a $n$-dimensional space is $n$ (by definition of the dimension of a space) and this means that you need $n$ independent coordinates, or $n$ independent base vectors in linear spaces, to fully describe it.

If you use a set of $n$ coordinates that are not linearly independent, you can't describe a a $n$ dimensional space.